# Liquid coding for disclaimer in cart field for any product containing product tag

Tags: input, attributes, tags, liquid, cart

I am currently using this code in the cart.liquid. I have tried it in the cart.template.liquid, but I need it to appear at the top of the cart container or near the products in the cart since the checkbox is required. I am new to coding, so please be specific. I used https://ui-elements-generator.myshopify.com/pages/cart-attribute to generate the required checkbox part. It said to insert it in the cart.liquid instead of the cart.template.liquid. ***Any advice would be awesome.***

```
   `{% for item in cart.items %}
      {% if product.tag contains "delay" %}
          <form>
            <p class="cart-attribute__field">
            <input type="hidden" name="attributes[I am aware that my order may have a 6 to 8-week 
            shipping delay, since there are higher than normal ordering volumes.]" value="No">
            <input required class="required" type="checkbox" name="attributes[I am aware that my 
            order may have a 6 to 8-week shipping delay, since there are higher than normal ordering 
            volumes.]" value="Yes"{% if cart.attributes["I am aware that my order may have a 6 to 8- 
            week shipping delay, since there are higher than normal ordering volumes."] == "Yes" %} 
            checked{% endif %}>
            <label>I am aware that my order may have a 6 to 8-week shipping delay, since there are 
             higher than normal ordering volumes.</label>
            </p><br>Not interested in waiting, check out alternative options for immediate shipping.  
            <a href="/collections/emergency-preparedness-survival-options"><b><i>SHOP NOW</i></b></a>
        </form>
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}`
```

Answer (score 0):

What theme are you using?

On newer themes the main cart content is in the *cart.template.liquid* file so you are in the right place.

The issue here is using `{% if product.tag contains "delay" %}` since the product object is not available. Instead, since you are looping through the cart items, the code should be:

`{% if item.product.tags contains "delay" %}`

What is happening here is the `item` variable is used to loop through all the cart line items. Using this you are then able to access the `product.tags` - note that it is "tags" as opposed to "tag" since it is an array of all the tags. More info on that can be seen [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/liquid/reference/objects/product#product-tags).

Hope that helps!